# Identification of proteins in this animation of a ribosome translating mRNA

Tags: translation, ribosome

[image]

This gif is from [this page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(biology))
After each aminoacyl-tRNA enters the ribosome, one blue thing comes and pushes the whole tRNAs whats that? I couldn't find it anywhere.(maybe some elongation factor?)
Also it seems that some thing is transporting the tRNA itself (maybe aminoacyl tRNA synthetase?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protein involved in "pushing" the tRNA and mRNA is the elongation factor [EF-G](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EF-G). The protein involved in "transporting" the tRNA is the elongation factor [EF-Tu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EF-Tu).

Quoted from the Wikipedia articles:

EF-G:

> When it binds to the ribosome A-site, EF-G causes the tRNA previously occupying that site to occupy an intermediate A/P position (bound to the A site of the small ribosomal subunit and to the P site of the large subunit), and the tRNA in the P site is shifted to a P/E hybrid state. EF-G hydrolysis of GTP causes a conformation change that forces the A/P tRNA to fully occupy the P site, the P/E tRNA to fully occupy the E site (and exit the ribosome complex), and the mRNA to shift three nucleotides down relative to the ribosome due to its association with these tRNA molecules. The GDP-bound EF-G molecule then dissociates from the complex, leaving another free A-site where the elongation cycle can start again

EF-Tu:

> The tRNA anticodon domain associates with the mRNA codon domain in the ribosomal A site. If the codon-anticodon pairing is correct, EF-Tu hydrolyzes guanosine triphosphate (GTP) into guanosine diphosphate (GDP) and inorganic phosphate. This creates a conformational change in EF-Tu that causes EF-Tu to dissociate from the tRNA of the ternary complex (and therefore leave the ribosome). The aminoacyl-tRNA then fully enters the A site, where its amino acid is brought near the P site's polypeptide and the ribosome catalyzes the covalent transfer of the polypeptide onto the amino acid . The tRNA on the P site (without peptide) moves to the E site and is then released.